# Recurring fee returned on getVirtualGuest is zero

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am doing the REST API getVirtualGuests by hostname and trying to get the recurring fees for the VM. I issue the following https request

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[datacenter,status,globalIdentifier,primaryBackendIpAddress,billingItem.currentHourlyCharge,billingItem.hourlyRecurringFee,billingItem.hoursUsed,billingItem.recurringFee,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.preset,billingItem.orderItem.preset,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.blockDevices,blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,frontendNetworkComponents,primaryBackendNetworkComponent,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress,userDataCount,userData]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"^=garycs-wdc07-rhel7"}}}
DEBUG: https return getting virtualguest

The json returned is:

"hourlyRecurringFee":"0","hoursUsed":"24","recurringFee":"0"

Shouldn't these fields contain some monetary amounts?

Comment: It seems that your VM is hourly therefore the recurring fee is 0.

Comment: How do I get the hourly charge for an hourly VM and Bare Metal?

Comment: "currentHourlyCharge" is the attribute that shows the hourly charge for an hourly VM and Bare Metal.

Comment: I added currentHourlyCharge to teh object mask and got back  'billingItem' => {
                             'hoursUsed' => '22',
                             'recurringFee' => '0',
                             'description' => '2 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores',
                             'createDate' => '2019-10-15T15:00:09-05:00',
                             'hourlyRecurringFee' => '0',
                             'currentHourlyCharge' => '0',      The currentHourlyCharge is zero

Comment: To get more information about the hourly VM and Bare Metal charge a suggest you to open a ticket, they will give you more details.